# Using database helper in static class [Code Igniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, class, static

I Have a static class dataaccess. I want to execute query. Usually in a controller or model class I will do :

```
$this->db
```

But in a static class I can't use this example, that is not allowed. Then I am using :

```
$CI = $ get_instance();
$CI->db->query .......
```

But I use many functions to send and get data with my database. One example :

```
public static function coursInsert($libelle) {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $sql = 'call coursInsert(?)';
        $CI->db->query($sql,$libelle);
    }
```

And my problem is : How can I create a `$CI =& get_instance();` but as a properties in my static class.

Like This :

```
class Dataaccess {

    private static $initialized = false;

    private static $CI = null;

    public static function intialize(){

        if (self::$initialized) {
            return;
        }
        self::$initialized = true;
        self::$CI =& getInstance(); 
    }
}
```

I tried and it doesn't work.

Did someone know if there is a way to not get an instance at every function that I am using to interact with my database ?

Comment: You'd be better of creating a singleton rather than a complete static class. i'm not sure how the statics variable are saved througout your application life cycle but from what i know, i'm not sure your static property $CI will be there when you want to access it.

Comment: With my last section code ? No it doesn't work but with my coursInsert function it work.

Comment: how and when do you call your method `intialize`? - _I tried and it doesn't work_ isn't really helpful - maybe you didn't realize your typo and tried to call `initialize`? you have to provide proper information - because your code looks fine ...

Comment: Have you installed the code igniter framework ?